# how to drop duplicated columns data based on column name in pandas

Tags: pandas

Assume I have a table like below

```
    A   B   C   B
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
```

I'd like to drop column B. I tried to use `drop_duplicates`, but it seems that it only works based on duplicated data not header.
Hope anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with `loc` or `iloc` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (~df.columns.duplicated())
[ True  True  True False]

df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  4  5  6
```

---

```
df = df.iloc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  4  5  6
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
cols = ['A','B','C','B']
#[1000 rows x 30 columns]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,30)),columns = np.random.choice(cols, 30))
print (df)

In [115]: %timeit (df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).first())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop

In [116]: %timeit (df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.58 ms per loop

In [117]: %timeit (df.iloc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()])
1000 loops, best of 3: 338 µs per loop

In [118]: %timeit (df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()])
1000 loops, best of 3: 346 µs per loop
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd definitely go with yours. It makes intuitive sense. You had my up-vote immediately. Mine is slightly fewer characters of code and a bit more flexible if you wanted to do other things. Useful... but I like yours better.

Comment: Found this old question I'm trying a new function to evaluate different timings. What do you think?

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can `groupby`
We use the `axis=1` and `level=0` parameters to specify that we are grouping by columns.  Then use the `first` method to grab the first column within each group defined by unique column names.

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()

   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  4  5  6
```

We could have also used `last`

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).last()

   A  B  C
0  0  3  2
1  4  7  6
```

Or `mean`

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()

   A  B  C
0  0  2  2
1  4  6  6
```